# Anchor link that needs double taps when touched/tap and single click when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, touch

I have this:

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one')
const two = document.getElementById('two')

one.onclick = () => console.log('one')
two.onclick = () => console.log('two')
```

```css
a {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: aliceblue;
}
div:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto
}
div {display: flex}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="one" href="#one">One</a>
  <a id="two" href="#two">Two</a>
</div>
```

When someone uses a mouse/trackpad, `:hover` will get triggered and they can see what they are clicking. Everything's fine.

But when someone touches anywhere inside the div, the `:hover` will get triggered after the touch and either link will receive an onclick event even when the user didn't know which one they were clicking.

Is there a way to make sure that touches/clicks get triggered only when the div is already visible?

One way I thought is:
An anchor link that works like usual when it is clicked by a mouse/trackpad but when it is touched/tapped it should only work on the second tap/touch. It is not necessary that the second tap must be in x seconds (like double click). The second tap can be anytime after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to distinguish a `tap` and a `click` with [jQuery Mobile plugin](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/).
But... A `tap` is has the same effect has a mouse click on a link.

I think I found something looking more like a *hack* than a clean standard solution. The trick is to move the real links away... And bring it back in position on the first tap/click. So the second tap/click will work.

I don't know if you will like it...
But it was a fun puzzle anyway.
;)

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // Hide the real links and create fake links
  $("#container a").each(function(i,val){
   $(this).parent().append( "<div class='fake LinkHidden' id='fake_" +$(this).attr("id")+ "'>" + $(this).html()+ "</div>" );
   $("#RealLink").append( $(this) );
  });
  
  var fromHoverFlag = false;
  // simulate hover for mouse and tap
  $(".fake").on("tap mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("LinkVisible LinkHidden");
   fromHoverFlag = true;
  });
  
  // onclick the visible fake links, replace html with a cloned version of the original link
  $("#container").on("tap click",".LinkVisible",function(){
   thatID = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
   
   //console.log("that Link ID: "+thatID[1]);
   // Clone the real link only on first click/tap
   if(fromHoverFlag){
    $(this).html( $("#RealLink #"+thatID[1]).clone() );
    console.log("Cloned link "+thatID[1]);
   }
  });
  
  // Restore the fake link on real click
  $("#container").on("click", ".fake a", function(){
   $(this).parent(".fake").toggleClass("LinkVisible LinkHidden");
   $(this).parent().html( $(this).html() );
   fromHoverFlag = false;
   console.log("Removed link "+thatID[1]);
  });
 });
```

```css
 a, .fake{
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:dodgerblue;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: aliceblue;
 }
 .LinkHidden {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 .LinkVisible{
  opacity:1;
 }

 div#container {display: flex}
 
 #RealLink{
  position:fixed;
  top:-1000px;
 }
 .bigDiv{
  height:1000px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="top"></a>
 <div id="container">
  <a id="one" href="#section_one">One</a>
  <a id="two" href="#section_two">Two</a>
 </div>
 <div id="RealLink"></div>
 
 <div class="bigDiv"></div>
 <a name="section_one"></a><br>
 ONE<br>
 <a href="#top">Back to top</a>
 <div class="bigDiv"></div>
 <a name="section_two"></a><br>
 TWO<br>
 <a href="#top">Back to top</a>
 <div class="bigDiv"></div>
```